# BigQuery Results to Panda DataFrame in Chunks

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to save the results of a BigQuery query to a Panda DataFrame using `bigquery.Client.query.to_dataframe()`

This query can return millions of rows.

Given that Panda to BQ (`Dataframe.to_gbq()`) has a chunk parameter, is there something similar for BQ to Pandas to incrementally add to the dataframe without having to run the query multiple times with a limit and offset?

Comment: The query is not running multiple times in `to_gbq()`; BQ results can be downloaded through pagination which is used in this method (it charges only one query execution). Still, if your result is relatively big, you're probably better off by first exporting results to GCS and then downloading from there.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `to_dataframe_iterable` instead to do this.

```py
job = client.query(query)
result = job.result(page_size=20)

for df in result.to_dataframe_iterable():
    # df will have at most 20 rows
    print(df)
```

Comment: I've noticed this often is ignored - for example if you pass a page_size of 100000 it will often downsize to 21875. is there a way to force the page size?

Answer (score 3):

How @William mentioned, you can chunk the BigQuery results and paginate them, the query will only charge one execution. I did this code based on official documentation using the public Dataset: 'bigquery-public-data.baseball.games_wide' as a demo:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

bq_client = bigquery.Client()

class BqToDfChunker(object):


    def __init__(self, query_job, results_per_page):
        bq_result = query_job.result()
        destination = query_job.destination
        destination =  bq_client.get_table(destination)

        self.destination = destination
        self.results_per_page = results_per_page
        self.num_pages = math.ceil(float(destination.num_rows/results_per_page))
        self.index = 0
        self.next_token = None


    def get_next_df_page(self):
        rows = bq_client.list_rows(self.destination,
           max_results = self.results_per_page,
           page_token = self.next_token)

        if self.index < self.num_pages:

            df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
            self.index += 1
            self.next_token = rows.next_page_token 

            return df

        else:
            return None


    def has_next(self):
        if self.index != self.num_pages:
            return True
        else:
            return False

if __name__ == '__main__':

    query = """
        SELECT homeTeamName FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.games_wide` group by homeTeamName
    """

    query_job = bq_client.query(query) 

    #initialize the class with the query_job and number_of_results_per_page
    bq_test = BqToDfChunker(query_job, 10)

    while bq_test.has_next():
        print(bq_test.get_next_df_page())
```

Comment: In my case, I had to change `df = pd.DataFrame(rows)` to `df = rows.to_dataframe()` to have a properly formatted pandas dataframe